# CollectionView layout

Tags: xcode, swift, layout, uicollectionview

Мне нужно, чтобы клетки 0 и 2 не имели отступ друг от друга. В идеале должно получиться что высота 0 и 2 клетки вместе = высоте клетки 1. Без отступов. Делаю через sizeForItemAtIndexPath. Все клетки находятся в одной секции.

[image]

Comment: Возможно нужно направление лейаута вертикальное сделать

Comment: Это не помогает..

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо унаследоваться от `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` и настроить все как необходимо, затем использовать для своей `UICollectionView`.

Хороший пример можете глянуть в [этой статье raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)